# React: I'm not able to access the images folder from pages folder

Tags: reactjs, image, path

I'm not able to access the images folder. components available in src directly are able to access the images folder but components in the pages folder are not able to access the images folder, tried different paths but not working.

[image]

```
import React from "react";
import TitleImg from "../images/title-text.png";
import eyes from "../images/eyes.png";

const Sad = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <img src={TitleImg} alt="the-sad-guys" />
      <img className="w-3/6" src={eyes} alt="eyes" />
    </>
  );
};

export default Sad;
```

Comment: this is not a react problem, it has to do with your bundler

Comment: I'm new to react, would be great if you can send show bit more detail about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example the route is not correct. `../../images/title-text.png` must work.

If this doesnt work, try

```
./../../images/title-text.png
```